# Specific word for "grown-up children"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for adult offspring? If all of your "children" are now in their adulthood, is there a specific word to refer to them?

Comment: No, _children_ does not necessarily imply childhood. I am still the child of my parents and will be until I die, no matter what my age.

Comment: @terdon that's true, but is there a specific word to avoid any ambiguity in conversation?

Comment: There is no word. I use **kids** when speaking to adults about my grown children, because it has less the connotation of youth (I think), but I have run into that problem myself. I sometimes feel the need to say, **my children, now adults...** or *my married children* when I want to avoid *kids*.

Answer (score 6):

Most groups and organizations use the phrase **adult child**(ren).

Comment: I find myself in the rare position of agreeing with RyeBread.  There is a group the ACA (Adult Children of Alcoholics) whose website is http://www.adultchildren.org  So, this is definitely a common usage.

Comment: @DavidM - The longer you know me the more you will agree with me.  I have delusional powers.

Comment: @terdon - I thought it was perfect.

Comment: @susan No, it was delusional.

Comment: @andy256 - exactly! I think it is a funny, self-deprecating and exceedingly accurate comment!

Comment: @terdon - Who doesn't have delusional powers?

Comment: @RyeBread - I used to, but I lost them when I went to the dentist. He pulled my special tooth. Damn him, if I had known, I would have insisted on a root canal.

Comment: @Susan - Delusion is the greatest gift.  Well that and smirking every day when Brad jumps online and I see my answers mass downvoted.

Comment: @Susan (and RyeBread) it is indeed, I just completely failed to parse it for some reason. I'll just quietly delete my comment now.

Comment: @RyeBread - keep it clean. Brad's a great guy. That very thing, though, happened to me, too, with another user. If you believe that, flag a comment and tell the mods. There's also an auto rollback on serial downvotes that kicks in a number of hours later, so they don't stick around.

Comment: @Susan - Brad keeps me coming back to the site.  I have no issues with the downvotes because I usually get a passionate explanation.  See one of my delusional powers is the ability to make a simple answer that greatly affects the mood of others through the internet.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that the word child(ren) has more than one meaning, or implied use. Consider the following sentence:

'My children (aged 36 and 32) constantly complain that I treat them as children'. That should illustrate what I mean.

And I have no doubt that these and other meanings will be confirmed by the OED.

Answer (score 0):

You could say offspring, though people would probably look at you strangely.

Comment: As long as people know I am speaking with 'a knowing sense of post-modernist irony' I feel perfectly at ease referring to mine as my 'offspring', my'progeny', my 'spawn', my 'brood', indeed 'the fruit of my loins'.

Comment: @WS2, I'd hide if you were my dad (mom?) and you referred to me as the "fruit of your loins".  I mean...ewwww! lol!

Comment: @kristina I think you have got the point!

Comment: @WS2 I've always taken "post-modernist" to be ironic. But isn't it more fun when people don't know?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Well, perhaps I did exaggerate. Don't tell them! But it was my daughter who came home from university after her first term claiming she could, wear anything, say anything etc. so long as she did it with 'kspmi'.